# format output while writing it to the output file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm reading a file and processing according to the need. As the output has tables, few columns are misaligned. I'm using while loop for processing of input read file.

Regexp:

```
$_ =~ s/$var/$mod{$var}/;
print "$_";
```

Please suggest me better way to format the output.

`col1 (40spaces) col2(nspaces) coln(nspaces)`

Here it is how i done it:
    open(MYFILE,'log')
    while() {
    if(condition)
    my($var) = (split ())[];
    $var =~ s/xyz/xy/;
    if($var = condition)
    $var = $1;
    }
    $_ =~ s/$var/$mod{$var}/;
    print "$_"

```
i need the output table 2nd column to be 40 spaces
```

Comment: Have you considered [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html)?  ([more docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html))

Comment: I use sprintf. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm totally beginner, so this is the first time im using output formatting. As the processing is done on the fly in a while loop and later using $_ for print, is there a way to format the output column ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rather than using `s///` on the whole line, you should split the line into fields, do what you need with each field, then output a formatted line using `printf`. Something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub trim { $_ = shift; s/(\A\s+)|(\s+\z)//gr }  # or use String::Trim

my %full_country_name = (
  ENG  => 'England',
  SCO  => 'Scotland',
  WAL  => 'Wales',
);

while (<DATA>)
{
  chomp;

  # Input columns are 4 chars, 5 chars, and everything else
  my ($number, $country, $letter) =
    map trim($_),
    m{^ (.{4}) (.{5}) (.+) $}x;

  # Output columns are 4 chars, 10 chars, and everything else
  printf(
    "%-4s%-10s%s\n",
    $number,
    $full_country_name{$country},
    $letter,
  );
}

__DATA__
1   ENG  A
2   SCO  B
3   WAL  C
```

**Update:** edited to include an implementation of the trim function.

Comment: Im getting error saying can't locate string/trim.pm. is it version issue ?

Comment: Then install String::Trim, or write a replacement `trim` function. Something like `sub trim { $_ = shift; s/(\A\s+)|(\s+\z)//gr }`